# Use different connection string based on the application url in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-config

I have a asp.net web project named *FinanceTracker* (which is under use for an year).
And the data is stored in `Finance_Tracker_db`.
(this is a intranet web site to track the financial data for an organization, accessed from 
`http://OrgTracker`)
Now I have a requirement to have the same application for IT department.
everything is same on the data for both should be segregated.
So I created an empty copy of database name `IT_Tracker_db`.(on same database server)
And used the old code with modified connection string in `web.config`
(accessed from `http://OrgTracker/IT/` deployed on same IIS server)

But as to have less maintenance to apply the same code to both deployed version, I am planning to use the same code with different connection strings.

Now I wish to have something like.

`http://OrgTracker/` - This should show two links

1. `http://OrgTracker/fincance/`
2. `http://OrgTracker/IT/`

And based on user selected URL the proper connection string should be used from web.config

Like all pages will remain same like.

`http://OrgTracker/fincance/Status.aspx`,  `http://OrgTracker/fincance/Inbox.aspx`, etc.

`http://OrgTracker/IT/Status.aspx`,  `http://OrgTracker/IT/Inbox.aspx`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Can have more than one config

[ASP.NET Configuration File Hierarchy and Inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not doing this. First, it is complicated and out of build-in ASP.NET functionality. 
Second, in some time in future your users can demand different things: one department would want newer version immediately, while the other one would want to have stable old version until they can test everything.

P.S. But if I were you, I'd start thinking about adding additional column called "Department" in all relevant tables so I could unite databases in future. This goes against my second point :), but it would make everything more manageable and architecturally sound, especially if  more departments would want to use your application.